# Why do I need TCP source and destination addresses?

Tags: networking, tcp, ip

A I know IP header has source and destination addresses.If so then why do I need TCP source and destination addresses? Can IP and TCP source and destination addresses differ? Or TCP destination address is not the real destination address.If not then why do i need TCP destination address?

Answer (score 4):

TCP addresses are called ports. See [*RFC 793, Transmission Control Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793):

> To allow for many processes within a single Host to use TCP
> communication facilities simultaneously, the TCP provides a set of
> addresses or ports within each host.  Concatenated with the network
> and host addresses from the internet communication layer, this forms a
> socket.  A pair of sockets uniquely identifies each connection. That
> is, a socket may be simultaneously used in multiple connections.

While IP addresses, at layer-3, will get packets to a host, TCP addresses, at layer-4, will get the segments to a process within the host.

Answer (score 2):

IP and TCP address fields do not overlap.

The IP header contains the Source and Destination Server's IP address (e.g. 167.206.112.138 is the IP address of Optimum Online's DNS server). The IP address allows your router, and all intermediate routers along the packet's route, to forward your packet either directly to its destination server, or to another router that is one step closer. Once the IP packet reaches its destination server, it has to be forwarded to a running service (process). That's where the Destination Port comes in, and that information is in the TCP header (as well as UDP's header).

So, IP will get you from one machine to another, and TCP/IP and UDP/IP gets you to a specific service, or process, by adding Port numbers.

Comment: This is a very good answer especially for a first answer. (First Posts Review) It goes into great detail and is easy to read.